# Using Custom String.xml value in config.java file

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

I'm Working in A new Project and I already coded config.java for my project

My config.java code

```
package com.egf.myapp;

public class Config {

public static final String APP_API_URL = "http://www.egypt-freelancers.me/en/index.php";

public static final String APP_IMAGES_URL = "http://www.egypt-freelancers.me/uploads/";

public static final String APP_IMAGES_THUMB_URL = "http://www.egypt-freelancers.me/uploads/thumbnail/";


public static final String LANGUAGE_EN = "en";
public static final String LANGUAGE_AR = "fr";
public static final String DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = LANGUAGE_EN;
```

how to replace APP_API_URL with
custom language string.xml value
For English
http://www.egypt-freelancers.me/en/index.php
For French
http://www.egypt-freelancers.me/fr/index.php

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `getString(...)` is for retrieving strings from your `strings.xml` resource file. You have listed strings in a custom Java class, which is an entirely unrelated concept.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understandings on the question you gave,

To get those variable values you can use this.

```
Config.STRING_VARIABLE_NAME;   // this will return you the value from that class and object creation for that class is not needed as the variable is static.
```

Example :

```
String myvalue = Config.APP_API_URL;
```